# 404 when listing packages via NugetCommandLine

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I'm getting a 404 when performing

```
nuget list -source http://mydomain/nuget
```

The 404 is actually coming from /Nuget/$metadata.

From the iis logs:

```
2011-10-17 23:24:27 172.27.72.94 GET /Nuget/$metadata - 80 - {ipAddress} - 404 0 2 46
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what may be causing this? FWIW I can successfully publish via the cmd.

Comment: I added a shared network folder to the app_data/packages directory and now I can use \\share\packages and that works fine.  Is that what you are supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I had to do:

```
nuget list -source http://mydomain/nuget/api/feeds
```

Comment: I have this bug and this didn't fix it for me.

Comment: For anyone coming later, using server v2.8 I had to use `nuget list -source http://server/nuget` in order to get a list back. this may be down to setup rather than anything else, but I don't have access to the server config.